# Why did common contractions become common?

Tags: contractions, speech

Examples:

> Real life isn't like that, y'know.
>
> Y'all are awesome.
>
> I dunno why.
>
> Where'd you go?

This is my theory: these phrases/sentences have been said so many times that people felt it would save a lot of time if they were contracted. But I don't know, I'm not a native English speaker, so maybe I'm wrong.

What do you think?

Comment: They didn't "feel" it would save a lot of time and then determine to pronounce things that way. They spoke like normal people spoke and it just happened.

Comment: I wanted to write something similar to Robusto's comment. Local slang or pronunciation and speaking very fast might have done the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking is articulation work, so it should not astonish that people everywhere in the world use contractions to speak faster and easier and save articulation work.

Answer (score 2):

Contractions aren't unique to English -- not even close.  Even just looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)), we can see examples from English, Chinese, French, Hebrew, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, German, Norwegian, Latin, Japanese, Polish, and Uyghur.

As @Daniel and @Robusto mention in comments, the construction of contractions doesn't appear to be a conscious decision, but rather a natural evolution of verbal shortcuts to written shortcuts.

Comment: I don't understand "a natural evolution of verbal shortcuts to written shortcuts". Written contractions are not "shortcuts"; they're a complex maze of workarounds and instead-ofs, with no useful rules and a general feeling of anxiety. Not what I'd call a shortcut. On the other hand, speech is **sposta** make shortcuts, and does. Constantly. Since writing is just technology -- visual representation of spoken language -- we should see some representation of those shortcuts in writing, but given English spelling and punctuation resources, we shouldn't really expect it soon.

Comment: Written contractions can be a frightening maze of rules if you're trying to have flawless grammar and write in a professional manner, but in common usage, they're just the written transcription of the way you'd phrase something while speaking. And `you'd` conveniently contains a full 50% fewer characters than the full `you would`, which is why I'm pretty comfortable referring to them as shortcuts. If you've got a better phrase to use here, I'm open to editing it in, though.

Comment: No, not at all. Apostrophes (which are inaudible, and thus not part of natural language) have been squozen into some places and forbidden in other's. In speech we cant tell the difference between _it's_ and _its_, so why bother in writing? And a silly contraption like _wouldn't've_ is just ridiculous when proffered as "the written transcription of the way you'd phrase something while speaking". You maybe, not me; _wouldna_ does the job nicely.

Comment: As clunky as "wouldn't've" is, @JohnLawler, I'm finding "wouldna" a little ambiguous...maybe "wouldnta" is clearer, for me, at least. :-)

Comment: But I don't pronounce a /t/. Id say _woodna_ if I could.

Comment: @John Lawler:  Since writing does not have the full range of physical immediacies that speech has (facial expression, tone of voice, rhythmic contours that demarcate clause and phrase boundaies, time/duration, etc) it is worse than speech at some things while being better than speech at others. To make speech the yardstick for determining what is optimal in writing would be a mistake. If writing devolved into a mere mirror of pronunciation, it would cease to be normalized; and it would be giving up some of the features it has developed to compensate for its lacking the immediacies of speech.

Comment: There is no "what is optimal in writing". Everybody learns to read and write in their own way, if they learn at all. What works for one person doesn't for another; hence "optimal" is meaningless unless speaking of one's own preferences. And, as a representation of English speech, English writing is better than Chinese characters, but not much better.

Answer (score 1):

Contractions in spelling are just ways to replicate the way the words are spoken. This isn't really any different than using 甭 instead of 不用 or 若 in place or 如果. These cases were not thought out or planned, they were just ways of replicating commonly spoken forms of the words.

One thing I learned while teaching English was that a lot of Chinese students do not realize that contractions are not acceptable in all contexts. Contractions are considered informal and are not appropriate for use in formal occasions such as business communications (letters, memos, press releases, etc), resumes, school essays, or other official or "proper" contexts. They are written words that sit on the boundary of what is considered acceptable and not in a language.

Some things to know about contractions:

English only half-accepts contractions. In some languages, contractions may eventually *become* standard words, as in the case of 若. In English, although we often create proper words from *blends* (smoke + fog == smog) it is uncommon for contractions to become *proper*. Still, we do set rules for correctly created contractions ("he doesn't," not "he don't"). These rules describe the boundary between correct speech and slang. The difference between unacceptably incorrect and slang is like the difference between dissonance and jazz; if you can pull it off with grace and style it is okay.

Informal examples (okay in personal letters, relaxed writing, non-business e-mail):
isn't 
he's 
wouldn't

Slang examples (okay in text to your texts to your friends and never anywhere else):

- wanna
- gonna

"Total fail" examples (never, ever do these):

- 4u (for you)
- u2 (you too)
- they doesn't
- he don't
- she wouldn't've

Comment: Why did you use Chinese examples? Because I have a Chinese surname and appearance?

Comment: That + you said English isn't your first language + I taught English in China for many years, so those are some of the best examples I have and the way I've taught the topic a few hundred times. I also like to show anyone reading that contractions are not always limited to alphabetic languages (a common misconception). :)

Comment: Ha, just joking. My parents are Taiwanese, so I know Chinese (my mother tongue is Spanish, though). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, there are a lot of Chinese students from both the mainland and Taiwan on here asking questions to improve their skills. I like to look for those questions because I miss being over there and teaching; I really loved relating the two languages.  So now I'm curious, what is your first language?

Comment: I was born in Chile and lived there for 18 years, so I guess my first language is Spanish (but my mom tough me in Chinese when I was a child). 

I see, I didn't know there were Taiwanese here.